# I am unable to retrieve tweets older than 7 days via twitter APIs

Tags: tweepy, tweets, twitter-api-v2

I have my Twitter developer researcher account, after creating apps in my account I am unable to scrap tweets older than 7 days using Twitter APIs

Answer (score 0):

I think the maximum number of days you can retrieve a tweet is 7 days